# DateTime of sprint backlog task status change to "Done"

Tags: tfs

Is there a field in TFS or any way to get the datetime value on which a sprint backlog task was changed to done?

I spotted an AuthorizedDate field but I'm not sure if it's out of the box or not.

Suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get TFS to do this for you if your template isn't already set up to do so.

Start the TFS Process editor (Install TFS power tools if needed), connect to TFS and edit the WIT Task.

Create a new field called (For Example) CompletedDate with a suitable reference name (For example: StackOverFlow.Questions.TaskCompletedDate).

Set it to be of type DateTime.

Next go to the workflow tab and do the following for each of the transitions to the done state:

1. Right Click, select open details
2. Select the fields tab, click new.
3. Enter the reference name of the field you create above  (StackOverFlow.Questions.TaskCompletedDate).
4. Select the Rules Tab and click new.
5. Select SERVERDEFAULT from the list of rules
6. On the dialog that appears, set the from field to clock.
7. Click OK, OK, OK to get back to the workflow.

Save the Work Item Definition.

See:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194981.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When your work item is set to done the closed date and closed by fields are set automatically.

These fields are part of all of the default templates.

Some of the older 2012 & 2013 templates did not include this for tasks and you would have to adds it', however you should use the out of the box provided fields and not create new ones. If you are reporting in this it's a nightmare if each work item type had its own way of doing things. Use the System.ClosedDate and System.ClosedBy field. You can copy the setup from the PBI or Bug work items..